# How to allow access to resource from client only in Spring Security OAuth2?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have developed a simple web-app using Spring-Boot with Spring Security OAuth2 and I want to allow access to all resources from the Client app only. Some resources will require the client to be authenticated while some will not.

I have the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/account/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
            .antMatchers("/transaction/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "password", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is for the resource "/account/**", it should not require the client to be authenticated but will still only allow access through client.

For the other resources, it will only allow access through the client and must be authenticated as well.

Unfortunately in the current setup above, I'm still able to access the "/account/**" from outside the client.

Appreciate any help.

**UPDATE 1**

Additional info I forgot to include, I'm using the grant_type password.

So what I want is this. For example:

/account - Should only be accessible with client_id/client_secret. Does not require user to be authenticated, meaning user does not need to have access token.

/user - Should only be accessible with client_id/client_secret. And requires user to be authenticated, meaning user must have access token.

Client I'm referring to is the Mobile Application that has the client_id and client_secret.

Let me know if I'm still not clear.

Comment: what do you mean by "it should not require the client to be authenticated but will still only allow access through client." - the **CLIENT** does not have to be authenticated, or the **USER**?

Comment: "only allow access through the client" and "should not require the client to be authenticated" seem to be contradictary goals. How can you control access if you can't authenticate the request?

Comment: I've updated my post above to explain further what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this then:

```
.authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/account/**").access("#oauth2.isClient()")
   .antMatchers("/user/**").access("#oauth2.isUser() && #oauth2.hasScope('read')")
```

Comment: I am getting the 401 Unauthorized error when using #oath2.isClient(). `curl -X POST -F client_id=my-trusted-client -F description=SomeUser -F email_address=someemail@somedomain.com -F pass
word=somepassword -i http://localhost:8080/account/registration` returns `{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}`

Comment: That's not an oauth2 request (no access token). You would need to get an access token and then add it to a header "-H Authorization: $TOKEN".

Comment: Ok. I see your point. But doesn't the user needs to be authenticated to get an access token? Or is there a way to generate this without authenticating? Reason I'm doing this is because I have a resource /account/register which takes in parameters and register the user. But I want to allow registration through the mobile app only. Not through the browser hence this is what I thought of doing.

Comment: You could authenticate a user registration with an access token I guess, but how would the client get a secret (doesn't really make much sense for a mobile client)? Most registration processes I see involve an unauthenticated request followed by a verification (eg email or sms). So in the context of this question you would want the initial POST to be unauthenticated I guess, but put the account in an inactive state.

Comment: If it's not a mobile client then access tokens make more sense of course.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Your comment made me realized that I'm going about this the wrong way. I wanted to secure the registration resource so that it won't be taken advantaged by spam/bot programs (Also the reason I neglected to use the approach wherein the account is inactive at first. Would create a lot of inactive account if abused by bots). I thought of another approach which is to setup a guest account in my server then use that as the initial authentication to get access token. Not sure if this will be efficient.

Comment: @ank Almost 4 years later I have the same requirement, I would like to authorize only the clients (web ui and mobile app) on some urls. I don't want to create a default user for this. Did you find a way? I know it's possible since the `/oauth/token` seems to be secured with http basic.

Comment: @akuma8 unfortunately no. i gave up on this approach and decided to just use a backend as as service instead.

Comment: @ank have u find any solutions?